# iOS Two custom views of dynamic height Autolayout

Tags: ios, dynamic, autolayout, xcode-storyboard

I'm working on autolayout, but I couldn't fix the error, so I'm posting for advice.

I am working on the cell of Table View which has two custom Views.
[image]

The views in question are Feed Content View and Detail Feed Type Content View.
The content of feed depends on the content of feed and the feed option.

[image]

set of automatic layout of feed content views.

[image]

set of automatic layout of feed type content views.

[image]

This is where the error occurs.

Thank you for your help every time, and I would appreciate any good comments and feedback.

Comment: Does your layout function correctly at run-time (does it look like you want it to look)? Do you get auto-layout warnings / errors in the debug console at run-time?